# Redis: How to update a key but do not change it's expiration time?

Tags: redis, set, ttl

Using Redis as cache service to cache some non-important data, and there is a case that need to update the value without reset or override the expire time, is there any good way to resolve this problem?
I've searched and found follows 2 solutions

1. Using **setrange** command, since the value is a little more complex, so it is not good in this situation.
2. Get the **ttl** time then set it as the expiration time when update the value. it's seems a little more redundant.

Any good idea to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another idea to so resolve this could be using [INCRBY](https://redis.io/commands/incrby).

For this you have to do some steps.

1. Get the existing value. For example, 10.
2. Determine the update value.For example, 17 .
3. INCRBY the value of their difference 17-10. That means, 7

This won't change the ttl

Comment: YES. Command INCRBY works fine when the value type is numerical type, but when the type is character data or String, it does not work.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to do any of those two things. You just need to use the `KEEPTTL` flag when you set your value.

Like this:

```
> set my_key this_is_my_value EX 60
```

This will set a value for a key with 60 seconds expiration.

Then, when you change the value and don't want to change the expiration of your key, just do:

```
> set my_key this_is_my_new_value KEEPTTL
```

More information on [REDIS docs](https://redis.io/commands/set).